# How select an element in CSS (using attribute) that is NOT a descendant of another element

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

After re-reading the CSS2.1 and CSS3 selector specs I *suspect* this is impossible, but you never know.

If I can select a p element, that is a decendent of other p element using the CSS decendant selector thus:

```
p p {};
```

Is there any way to negate the decendant selector, and still select on type, so I can select p elements, except those that are decendents of other p elements...

```
p & ( p ! p ) {...};
```

i.e. I want to select elements of type p, but NOT if they decend from other elements of type p.

BTW: I am using this in querySelector() and querySelectorAll(), where each one is selected by attributes not tag type, but I wanted to show the simplest example possible...

I tried this without success (syntax error!)

```
p:not(p p) {......}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You suspect correctly, it is impossible. `:not(s)` specifies that `s` must be a *simple selector*.

The nearest thing you can do is to apply a style to all `p` and then override it for `p p`.

Answer (score 2):

```
*:not(h1) p {
  ...
}
```

This is called the `negation pseudo-class`, and you can find more informations about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).

By the way, it is CSS3 so you can't use it with IE versions prior to 8.

Comment: Sorry, I realized my explanation was not accurate and had to change it!

Comment: That won't work. It means "A p element that is descended from an element that is not an h1". It doesn't mean "A p element that is not descended from an h1". Since `*:not(h1)` will match `<html>` and since every `<p>` is descended from the `<html>` (including ones that are also descended from `<h1>`) it will match **every** paragraph.

Comment: You're right. I let this my answer anyway, to help people who don't know this selector.

Answer (score 1):

While the `:not(...)` selector is only CSS3, I usually use this for CSS2 compatibility:

```
p { color: #abc; border: ... ; ... }
h1 > p { color: inherit; border: inherit; ... }
```

If your `<p>`s have a common ancestor, i.e. your html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <p> ... </p>
    <p>
        <p> ... </p>
        <p> ... </p>
    </p>
</body>
```

you can use the "direct-child" selector:

```
body > p { ... }
```

Or, of course, resetting all properties with something like:

```
p p { color: inherit; background: inherit; ... }
```

would work too..

Comment: Sorry, I realized my explanation was not accurate and had to change it!